# Interface field [field].contentful_id expects type String! but [another_field].contentful_id is type String. with Gatsby v3 & Contentful

Tags: graphql, gatsby, contentful

Beginning with Gatsby and using https://github.com/ryanwiemer/gatsby-starter-gcn. Just updated to v3 and the latest of all gatsby- plugins and getting:

> ERROR #11321  PLUGIN
>
> "gatsby-node.js" threw an error while running the createPages lifecycle:
>
> Interface field ContentfulReference.contentful_id expects type String! but
> ContentfulAsset.contentful_id is type String.

In `gatsby-node.js` is:

```
createTypes(`
  interface ContentfulReference {
    contentful_id: String!
    id: ID!
  }
`);
  createTypes(schema.buildObjectType({
    name: `ContentfulAsset`,
    fields: {
      contentful_id: {
        type: `String!`
      },
      id: {
        type: `ID!`
      }
    },
    interfaces: [`ContentfulReference`, `Node`]
  }));
```

It is happening for several others too (all of which have `contentful_id: String!`):

> Interface field ContentfulReference.contentful_id expects type String! but
> ContentfulPage.contentful_id is type String.
>
> Interface field ContentfulEntry.contentful_id expects type String! but
> ContentfulPage.contentful_id is type String.
>
> Interface field ContentfulEntry.node_locale expects type String! but
> ContentfulPage.node_locale is type String.
>
> Interface field ContentfulReference.contentful_id expects type String! but
> ContentfulPost.contentful_id is type String.
>
> Interface field ContentfulEntry.contentful_id expects type String! but
> ContentfulPost.contentful_id is type String.
>
> Interface field ContentfulEntry.node_locale expects type String! but
> ContentfulPost.node_locale is type String.
>
> Interface field ContentfulReference.contentful_id expects type String! but
> ContentfulTag.contentful_id is type String.
>
> Interface field ContentfulEntry.contentful_id expects type String! but
> ContentfulTag.contentful_id is type String.
>
> Interface field ContentfulEntry.node_locale expects type String! but
> ContentfulTag.node_locale is type String.

Comment: It's hard to tell what's going on here, but it's better to open an issue in the starter GitHub repo. The maintainer might be able to help out or update the starter.

Answer (score 0):

According to:

> Interface field ContentfulReference.contentful_id expects type String!
> but ContentfulAsset.contentful_id is type String.

And because of the `!` (nullability/non-nullability) it seems that your `contentful_id` is `null` in some fields so it breaks the contract of your defined interface. I'm not sure what's causing your issue because given the provided data it's difficult to guess, but I would try removing the nullability of the field (with `!`, you are telling to the interface that `contentful_id` will be always non-nullable) or checking all your references to detect which one is `null`.

```
  interface ContentfulReference {
    contentful_id: String
    id: ID!
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing the exact same problem. Deleting `src/gatsby/schema/schema.gql` and running `npm run clean`, `npm run develop` should regenerate the schema, and allow the site to work again.

The [answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69249100/16977540) and [this issue comment](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/28527#issuecomment-740536363) clued me in to the issue: the schema snapshot stored in `src/gatsby/schema/schema.gql` from [`gatsby-plugin-schema-snapshot`](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-schema-snapshot/) has become outdated and `contentful_id` was likely marked as nullable in later versions of the API.